# Programmatically access favorite and recent contacts in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, addressbook, abaddressbooksource

Apple introduced [favorite and recent contacts in iOS 8](http://www.imore.com/how-use-multitasking-contacts-ios-8), essentially an overlay that shows a sub-group of contacts. I've looked around a bunch but haven't seen a way to access that list. Is there any way through the API to access those?

Assuming it isn't possible, are there any other ways to access metadata around contacts in iOS 8?

Comment: No this is not possible, there is no public API in the iOS SDK.